# Error displaying visual studio code C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

How do I get Visual Studio Code indicates an error in a C++ code?

Installed extensions: С/С++; С/С++ Clang and C++ and C++ Intellisense.

Set the path:

```
    "name": "Win32",
    "includePath": [
        "D:/programm/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/include/c++"
    ],
    "browse": {
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
```

but errors are not displayed.

Comment: Does your extension know about compiler path?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Visual Studio Code indicates errors, create a simple project and use the next VScode configuration:

1. Install next plugins `C/C++`, `C/C++ Clang Command Adapter`, `C++ Intellisense`, `Easy C++ projects`
2. Open new folder (File -> Open Folder)
3. Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type `Easy Cpp/C++: Create new C++ project`
4. Add the file `.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json` with the next content:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\include",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.10150.0\\ucrt"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

4. Check out the configuration by pressing F7.

If you see in a terminal the "Hello Easy C++ project!" message, hence the configuration is done.
You can easily modify this configuration for your needs.

**Possible difficulties:**

- make sure that your configuration has the correct include paths in `c_cpp_properties.json`
- if you are using a VisualStudio toolchain, make sure the `build.bat` file has the right path to the compiler.
- if you are using clang as a compiler, make sure the `clang.executable` are set up in a Workspace Settings